# JavaScript - How can I play multiple videos at once?

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

I have an `array` of video elements that I wish to play at the same time.

The only way I've found online that I could do this would be to use `new MediaController();` but that doesn't seem widely/if at all supported.

What I was expecting to do was:

```
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
var mc = new MediaController();
video.forEach(function(el) {
    el.controller = mc;
});
mc.play();
```

The only way I've found to do this is doing a `forEach` on the array and playing them one after another, but I was wondering if anyone know if there might be a way to do this, but you notice a slight delay between `video[0]` and `video[4]` when playing.

Is it even possible to get this to be seemless with JavaScript?

P.S. This'll only need to be a Webkit solution as this isn't really something for a browser, but more for a front end for a UE4 game.

Comment: One hacky way to bypass multiple playback limitations is to stitch many videos into one, and change the viewport while zooming in. You'd have to use the same audio for all videos, though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think that'd be possible as the videos are dynamic, based on the rarity of the elements the video sit in so that'd mean creating a load more videos rather than the 4 rarities I currently have.

Answer (score 5):

My hypothesis is that they don't play at once because they are loading asynchronously. I would suggest to wait for ready state of all videos and then play them one by one. Here is an example of how you can achieve this with Promise.

```js
// Get all videos.
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');

// Create a promise to wait all videos to be loaded at the same time.
// When all of the videos are ready, call resolve().
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
  var loaded = 0;

  videos.forEach(function(v) {
    v.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
      loaded++;

      if (loaded === videos.length) {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
});

// Play all videos one by one only when all videos are ready to be played.
promise.then(function() {
  videos.forEach(function(v) {
    v.play();
  });
});
```

```html
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Did you try different video sources? I suppose, browser is caching media from same URL

Comment: mmm I tried it in chrome and firefox and it does not work