# Play two videos "simultaneously"

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

im trying to play two videos and i want them  playing "at the same time".

```
var videoEnergy = document.getElementById("energyVideo");
var videoHydration = document.getElementById("hydrationVideo");
```

So my plan is to only play the videos if both are loaded. I tried a solution posted here:
[JavaScript - How can I play multiple videos at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254716/javascript-how-can-i-play-multiple-videos-at-once).

```
var videos = [videoEnergy,videoHydration];



// Create a promise to wait all videos to be loaded at the same time.
// When all of the videos are ready, call resolve().
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
  var loaded = 0;

  videos.forEach(function(v) {
    v.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
      loaded++;

      if (loaded === videos.length) {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
});
// Play all videos one by one only when all videos are ready to be played.
promise.then(function() {
  videos.forEach(function(v) {
    v.play();
  });
});
```

Locally this solutions works, but when i uploaded to the server the videos doesnt play, they get stuck , the promise never gets resolved.

I tried kind of a recursive solution my own but it doesent even work locally:

```
function callback1(){
    if (videoHydration.readyState>3){
        videoEnergy.play();
        videoHydration.play();
    }
    else{
        callback1();
    }
}

function callback0(){
    if (videoEnergy.readyState>3){
        videoHydration.addEventListener("canplaythrough",callback1());
    }
    else{
        callback0();
    }
}

videoEnergy.addEventListener("canplaythrough",callback0());
```

Any ideas how to get through this? im not so good at javascript yet.

Comment: Do you have any caching system?

Comment: Im not quite sure whats a caching system, but from what i googled i would say i dont.